# Delete Documents that have the same of certain field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a data in MongoDB and I want to remove all the duplicated Documents. The problem is MongoDB assigns each item a unique `_id` so I can't just delete the duplicated items. I have a field in each Document called `name` and I want to delete the items that have the same `name`.
For example:

```
[{_id: 5c7e423f0bdaa9aeb5399e90,
name ="A"
grade = 16
enrolled ="dddh"
},

{_id: 5c7e423f1bdaa9aeb5399e90,
key ="B"
grade =17
note ="ddddd"
},

{_id: 5c7e423d0bdaa9aeb5399e90,
key ="B"
score =17
note ="ddddd"
}]
```

to:

```
[{_id: 5c7e423f0bdaa9aeb5399e90,
name ="A"
grade = 16
enrolled ="dddh"
},

{_id: 5c7e423f1bdaa9aeb5399e90,
name ="B"
grade =17
enrolled ="ddddd"
}]
```

The list might be big so is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: Note as you state yourself *"MongoDB assigns each item a unique _id"* but you posted the question with data showing the same `_id` values due to "copy/paste". This could be ( and was ) confusing to people viewing the question. Also Documents in MongoDB are not JSON, which further confuses things when you use that term

Comment: _id values are differenf in the qeustion. Also I'm asking about JSON array. Documents in MongoDB are not JSON but after I processed them with JS they became JSON.

Comment: Read the links. You can return the data with the "duplicates" removed

Comment: I have read the links previously and it didn't work in my query because `distinct()` doesn't work with `sort()` and `find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note your structure contains a lot of syntax errors. Now, one solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over your original array of objects to generate a new `object` using the `name` properties as the `keys` of this new object. This will ensure you will end up with only one object associated per `name` property. Finally, you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get your desired output.

```js
let input = [
  {
    _id: "5c7e423f0bdaa9aeb5399e90",
    name: "A",
    grade: 16,
    enrolled: "dddh"
  },
  {
    _id: "5c7e423f1bdaa9aeb5399e90",
     name: "B",
     grade: 17,
     note: "ddddd"
  },
  {
    _id: "5c7e423d0bdaa9aeb5399e90",
    name: "B",
    score: 17,
    note: "ddddd"
  }
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    acc[curr.name] = acc[curr.name] || curr;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: The question is poorly titled. It's actually asking about "documents in a MongoDB collection" and not an "Array of Objects in JavaScript", which is what you have answered.

Comment: "Array of Objects in JavaScript" is exactly what I am asking... The answer worked perfectly. Thank you.